# wp_insert_post_data hook should be called before updating db but isn't

Tags: hooks

```
function custom_editing_permissions($data, $postarr)
{
    //Post gets updated here WTF?
     die;

}
//Hook should be called "prior to inserting into or updating the database"
add_filter('wp_insert_post_data', 'custom_editing_permissions', 1, 2 );
```

https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/wp_insert_post_data

What is going on here? Running on version 4.4.1.

Comment: Please add some context and explain how you test this.